# Updating a variable within a loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, command, increment

amateur script coder here and I am seeking some assistance in getting my loop script to work in the desired way.

So I have a list of 9 IP addresses to ping, which are stored within variables set with 2 letters followed by 1 digit, as you can see below.

I think there are two issues I am facing, that I can see anyway.
The first is that when trying to call up the IP stored within the variable, it actually tries to ping the name of the the variable I want, not the IP within the variable I want to call upon.

The second problem I am aware of is how to increment that digit of the variable. IE how to make "AP1" increment to "AP2" and so on.

Help! :(

Below is a cut-down version of my script to demonstrate my circumstances. In the full script there are many many different 'sites'

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

:SET_SITE_ID
echo There are 3 customers set up: [1] [2] [3]
set /p SITE="Enter Site ID: "
goto %SITE%

:VERIFY_SITE_ID
cls
echo                 Site ID set to: %SITE%
echo                       Location: %LOCATION%
echo          The number of AP's is: %AP_QUANTITY%
echo           The controller IP is: %CONTROLLER%
echo                         AP1 IP: %AP1%
if defined AP2 echo                         AP2 IP: %AP2%
if defined AP3 echo                         AP3 IP: %AP3%
if defined AP4 echo                         AP4 IP: %AP4%
if defined AP5 echo                         AP5 IP: %AP5%
if defined AP6 echo                         AP6 IP: %AP6%
if defined AP7 echo                         AP7 IP: %AP7%
if defined AP8 echo                         AP8 IP: %AP8%
if defined SITE_NOTES echo Site Notes: %SITE_NOTES%
choice /C 12 /N /M "Is the above info correct? [1=Proceed to Ping Test] [2=Change it]"
if %errorlevel%==1 goto PING_TEST
if %errorlevel%==2 goto SET_SITE_ID

:PING_TEST
cls
choice /C 12 /N /M "Which test script? [1=Original] [2=Stephan's script]"
if %errorlevel%==1 goto PING_TEST_ORIGINAL
if %errorlevel%==2 goto PING_TEST_STEPHAN

:PING_TEST_ORIGINAL
cls
echo Starting ping test.
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Testing Controller...
ping -n 2 %CONTROLLER%
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Testing AP1 (of %AP_QUANTITY%)...
ping -n 2 %AP1%
if not defined AP2 goto END_OF_PING_TEST
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Testing AP2 (of %AP_QUANTITY%)...
ping -n 2 %AP2%
if not defined AP3 goto END_OF_PING_TEST
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Testing AP3 (of %AP_QUANTITY%)...
ping -n 2 %AP3%
if not defined AP4 goto END_OF_PING_TEST
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Testing AP4 (of %AP_QUANTITY%)...
ping -n 2 %AP4%
if not defined AP5 goto END_OF_PING_TEST
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Testing AP5 (of %AP_QUANTITY%)...
ping -n 2 %AP5%
if not defined AP6 goto END_OF_PING_TEST
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Testing AP6 (of %AP_QUANTITY%)...
ping -n 2 %AP6%
if not defined AP7 goto END_OF_PING_TEST
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Testing AP7 (of %AP_QUANTITY%)...
ping -n 2 %AP7%
if not defined AP8 goto END_OF_PING_TEST
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Testing AP8 (of %AP_QUANTITY%)...
ping -n 2 %AP8%
if not defined AP9 goto END_OF_PING_TEST
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Testing AP9 (of %AP_QUANTITY%)...
ping -n 2 %AP9%
goto END_OF_PING_TEST

:PING_TEST_STEPHAN
set count=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set AP') do (
set /a count+=1
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo testing %%a, [!count! of %AP_QUANTITY%]
ping -n 2 %%a
)
goto END_OF_PING_TEST

:END_OF_PING_TEST
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
choice /C YN /M "End of ping test. Repeat?"
if %errorlevel%==1 goto PING_TEST
if %errorlevel%==2 exit

:1
set LOCATION=Customer 1
set AP_QUANTITY=1
set CONTROLLER=192.168.0.253
set AP1=192.168.0.252
set SITE_NOTES=Notes go here
goto VERIFY_SITE_ID

:2
set LOCATION=Customer 2
set AP_QUANTITY=2
set CONTROLLER=192.168.0.253
set AP1=192.168.0.252
set AP2=192.168.0.111
set SITE_NOTES=Notes go here
goto VERIFY_SITE_ID

:3
set LOCATION=Customer 3
set AP_QUANTITY=9
set CONTROLLER=192.168.0.253
set AP1=192.168.0.252
set AP2=192.168.0.111
set AP3=192.168.0.8
set AP4=127.0.0.1
set AP5=127.0.0.1
set AP6=127.0.0.1
set AP7=127.0.0.1
set AP8=127.0.0.1
set AP9=127.0.0.1
set SITE_NOTES=Notes go here
goto VERIFY_SITE_ID
```

Comment: oh, sorry. Windows command line batch file

Answer (score 0):

only small changes needed: using delayed expansion and corrected `if` syntax (it's `==` instead of `=`)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set AP_QUANTITY=8
set AP1=192.168.0.182
set AP2=192.168.0.183
set AP3=192.168.0.184
set AP4=192.168.0.185
set AP5=192.168.0.186
set AP6=192.168.0.187
set AP7=192.168.0.188
set AP8=192.168.0.189
set APS_YET_TO_PING=%AP_QUANTITY%
set AP_TO_PING=AP1

:PING_APS
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo Testing !%AP_TO_PING%! (of %AP_QUANTITY%)
ECHO ping -n 2 !%AP_TO_PING%!
echo ----------------------------------------------------
set /a AP_TO_PING=%AP%+1
REM above line won't work like you want.
set /a APS_YET_TO_PING=%APS_YET_TO_PING%-1
REM another syntax: set /a APS_YET_TO_PING -=1
echo AP's remaining to ping=%APS_YET_TO_PING%
echo Next AP=%AP_TO_PING%
pause
if "%APS_YET_TO_PING%"=="0" goto END
goto PING_APS

:END
ECHO Ping test complete
pause
```

To show you another way (using a `for /f` loop), resulting in a nice short code:
`set _ap` lists all variables with names that start with `_ap` (Note: use unique beginnings, there are variables like `appdata`, so I started with an underscore).

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Quantity=8
set count=0
set _AP1=192.168.0.182
set _AP2=192.168.0.183
set _AP3=192.168.0.184
set _AP4=192.168.0.185
set _AP5=192.168.0.186
set _AP6=192.168.0.187
set _AP7=192.168.0.188
set _AP8=192.168.0.189
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set _AP') do (
  set /a count+=1
  echo testing %%a, [!count! of %Quantity%]
  echo ping -n 2 %%a
)
```

(Note: I "disabled" the ping commands in both scripts with an `ECHO` to make the code work faster and avoid ping errors. Just remove the `ECHO` after troubleshooting)

**Edit 2**

Try the following :

```
...
:PING_TEST_STEPHAN
set count=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set AP') do (
set /a count+=1
echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------
echo testing %%a, [!count! of %AP_QUANTITY%]
ECHO ping -n 2 %%a
)
goto END_OF_PING_TEST
...
```

See my reason to use `_AP...` instead of `AP...` above!
If you are unsure how it works, try it with `echo on`. Also `for /?` should help.

The `for /f` takes every line of the output of `set AP`, `"tokens=2 delims=="` cuts out the second part (called 'token') when splitting it at the `=` (token1 = `AP<n>`, token2 = "". This is my reason to use `_AP<n>`, so `set _AP` does ONLY show the IP's, not `%APPDATA%` and `AP_QUANTITY`. You'll have to change it too at the site-definitions.

Note you can simplify your `:VERIFY_SITE_ID` with the single line

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('set AP') do echo          %%a
```

instead of all those `if defined ...` lines. (NOTE: change to `set _AP`, reason above)
or to keep closer to your output:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('set AP') do echo          %%a IP: %%b
```

Comment: Thank you - really helped! :)

Comment: Hi Stephan - thanks for this. It works well however there needs to be a method to end the loop earlier should there be less AP's to ping; hence the APS_YET_TO_PING variable in my original thought. If the tokens were to increment to 3 could then that be implemented? Perhaps if when !count! is equal to %Quantity% ?

Comment: That's the nice thing, that `for` does for you. It iterates over all `_AP<x>`. No need to know, how many there are. Alternatively, you can also have a file (instead of a lot of varables) (just one IP per line) and iterate over all lines `for /f "delims=" %%a in (ip-addresses.txt) do ...`; no need to set any variables at all. In my second example, there is not even a need for `count` and `quantity`. It's just to show the progress to the user.,

Comment: Hi Stephan - I don't understand your solution, sorry! Could you re-phrase it please?

Having all the IP addresses in a separate file would make most not reply because there are many different IP's to ping depending upon location and each location have it's own range. I've put together a cut-down version of my script to help demonstrate...

Comment: The comments box won't take the script, so I've edited my original post to show the script I mentioned

Comment: See my Edit2. I tried to include some explanations. Try to learn more about `for`. It's the most powerful command in batch.

Comment: excellent, thanks Stephan. I'll check it out and take your advise about the FOR command. It does seem very powerful!